# Using foreign key in SQL server and DB locks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-keys, database-deadlocks

I have been working with SQL Server for a long time I always use FKs and indexes when a logic connection between tables exist

Example:

```
MyTable1
{
    ID      BIGINT IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL,
    SomeData    NVARCHAR(255)       NOT NULL,
    MyFK        BIGINT          NULL -- this is a FK to MyTable2.ID
}

MyTable2
{
    ID      BIGINT IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL,
    SomeData    NVARCHAR(255)       NOT NULL
}
```

Now to the problem,
When I execute some bulk update operations on MyTable1 that update MyFK,
and in the same time execute an insert statements to MyTable2, we hang till a timeout occur or the update is done and the locks are released.

As far as I know when inserting to a table that has FKs, the DB engine needs to get a lock on the relevant table to validate the FK, and that is the source for the problem.

Things I tries to resolve the problem:

- removed the lock escalation option on the table http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
- Changing the locks on the index to be row based and not page based
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189076%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Both solutions lead me to deadlocks and bad performance.

When I removed the FK, it all worked well, but there is the risk of data corruption.

Questions:

1. Is there any recommended set of rules on where to use a FK and where not to?
2. Can you offer me any other solution but removing the FK to overcome my problem?

Comment: Be hard without the bulk update code, as I can't see why you are getting the problem in the first place. One regular trick to speed up bulk queries, is to drop the keys first and then put them back (with check) afterwards

Comment: One integration module in our system is used to import data from outside sources. When we do so, we use SQLBulkCopy to load the data to a table in the DB, do some select operations on it and than we do something like
    Update MyTable1
    Set MyFK = T2.ID From MyTable1 inner Join MyTempTable On...

Comment: Is the db in full use when you do it? I don't get where the lock is coming from given what you've described. Should skip through quite happily, not going to lock itself out unless you've done something a bit off beat.

Comment: This post represents my situation perfectly.
http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/02/01/blocking-on-foreign-keys-in-sql-server/
Now that I've found it I can try the solutions they suggest.
Will update if I'll find anything worth mentioning.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I thought you were saying the bulk update was locking itself out, seeing as there was no mention of bulk updating where the db was in use. Generally I try to do that sort of thing in single user mode. Another option might be to break the updates up into manageable segments, cut down the chances of a long term collision.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case the [page](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/02/01/blocking-on-foreign-keys-in-sql-server/) asasfrob found goes down, the answer it gave was:

> Define the primary key on the parent table (TableA) as a non-clustered
>   index.  Once you do that, the issue won’t occur since the look-up will
>   occur against the non-clustered index and that won’t be in a locked
>   state since the PK column is not being modified.